# How to set cookies using javascript in VF page and read the cookies in controller

Tags: visualforce

I am developing VF page which is used in Force.com site. In VF page user can enter the value in input field and refresh the page. Currently all value is lost. We want to retain that value once page is reload. For this I have created cookie using JavaScriptand then try to read that cookie value in controller.

***********Page************************

```
<apex:page controller="CookiesClass" id="pgid">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <script>
        function setCookies(name){
            var subId=document.getElementById("pgid:frmid:cookieName").value
            var curdate = new Date();
            curdate.setMonth(curdate.getMonth() + 9);
            cookieExpires = curdate.toUTCString();
            final_cookie =  encodeURIComponent(subId) + ";expires_on = " + cookieExpires;
            document.cookie = apex__final_cookie;
        } 
    </script>
    <apex:form id="frmid" style="background-color:white;border-color:#555;">
        Name<apex:inputText value="{!inputCookie}" label="Name" id="cookieName"  onkeypress="setCookies(this.id)" />
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

******Controller************************

```
public class CookiesClass {
    public string inputCookie{
        get {
            Cookie cName = ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies().get('apex__final_cookie');
            system.debug('cName ********'+cName);
            if(cName == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return cName.getValue();
        }set{}
     }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a lot of mismatched variable names in your code, which is probably the problem.

In the Visualforce page:

1. Your JavaScript example is called with the value "cookieName"
2. The setCookies parameter, `name`, does not appear to ever be used
3. You set the cookie value to the variable `final_cookie` but never use it
4. You set `document.cookie` to the value "apex__final_cookie" but that is not declared in the sample code provided

In your controller, you expect the cookie to be named "apex__final_cookie".

First I would make sure your variable names are straight; you can work through that with tools like Firebug or the Chrome developer tools. These will allow you to debug the JavaScript and inspect your cookies. You may also want to review an example like [this one](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_sites_cookie.htm) that shows working with cookies in Visualforce controllers.